# Javascript Lodash sort by external array and internal property

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have an array of people that I need to sort by a defined external array (order) and then by age.  I am using lodash `sortBy`

```
const _  = require('lodash');
const arr = [
  { name: "Mandy", age: "34" },
  { name: "Shelly", age: "32" },
  { name: "Kyle", age: "12" },
  { name: "Kyle", age: "60" },
  { name: "Mandy", age: "32" },
  { name: "Mandy", age: "99" },
  { name: "Shelly", age: "30" },
  { name: "John", age: "3" },
  { name: "John", age: "1" },
  { name: "John", age: "6" },
  { name: "Mandy", age: "3" }
];

let order = ["Shelly", "John", "Mandy", "Kyle"];

let sortedArrByOrder = _.sortBy(arr, [person => order.indexOf(person.name), 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);

console.log(sortedArrByOrder);
```

But the age is not sorted  in desc order.  Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_.sortBy()` doesn't except order (asc / desc), use [`_.orderBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) instead:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Mandy", age: "34" },{ name: "Shelly", age: "32" },{ name: "Kyle", age: "12" },{ name: "Kyle", age: "60" },{ name: "Mandy", age: "32" },{ name: "Mandy", age: "99" },{ name: "Shelly", age: "30" },{ name: "John", age: "3" },{ name: "John", age: "1" },{ name: "John", age: "6" },{ name: "Mandy", age: "3" }];

const order = ["Shelly", "John", "Mandy", "Kyle"];

const sortedArrByOrder = _.orderBy(arr, [person => order.indexOf(person.name), 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);

console.log(sortedArrByOrder);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

In addition, using `Array.indexOf()` (O(n)) inside a sort operation (O(nLogn) for array with more than 10 items), might hurt the performance. A better way would be to convert the `order` array to a data structure with O(1) retrieval like an Map or plain object, and store the original index from the array. Now you can get the original index directly:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Mandy", age: "34" },{ name: "Shelly", age: "32" },{ name: "Kyle", age: "12" },{ name: "Kyle", age: "60" },{ name: "Mandy", age: "32" },{ name: "Mandy", age: "99" },{ name: "Shelly", age: "30" },{ name: "John", age: "3" },{ name: "John", age: "1" },{ name: "John", age: "6" },{ name: "Mandy", age: "3" }];

const order = new Map(["Shelly", "John", "Mandy", "Kyle"].map((s, i) => [s, i]))

const sortedArrByOrder = _.orderBy(arr, [person => order.get(person.name), 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);

console.log(sortedArrByOrder);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: strange, that `_` has two methods for nearly the same.

Comment: The sortBy method is in lodash since 0.1.0, while orderBy was added in 4.0.0. They couldn't remove sortBy due to backward compatibility probably.

Comment: Since I am sorting the name using another list, does it matter what I put for for ascending or descending for the first order?  `['asc', 'desc']`

Comment: You are not sorting the `name` using another list, you are using the `name` and another list to product the value by which the array is sorted. Since this is a value, the sort order matters. You can change it to `desc` and see.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a callback and return the negative age and omit the array for the order.

```js
const
    arr = [{ name: "Mandy", age: "34" }, { name: "Shelly", age: "32" }, { name: "Kyle", age: "12" }, { name: "Kyle", age: "60" }, { name: "Mandy", age: "32" }, { name: "Mandy", age: "99" }, { name: "Shelly", age: "30" }, { name: "John", age: "3" }, { name: "John", age: "1" }, { name: "John", age: "6" }, { name: "Mandy", age: "3" }],
    order = ["Shelly", "John", "Mandy", "Kyle"],
    sortedArrByOrder = _.sortBy(arr, [
        ({ name }) => order.indexOf(name),
        ({ age }) => -age
    ]);

console.log(sortedArrByOrder);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```